# On Android Context.getCacheDir() seems to return a directory I cannot create subdirectories in

Tags: android, file, caching, permissions, subdirectory

Does Android not allow creating subdirectories in the cacheDir?  Given that third party (such as advendors) surely will need to cache their own files, it makes lots of sense for me to create a subdirectory for my cached files and let third parties I've integrated manage their own cached files.

Does anyone know how to set the permissions so you can create subdirectories?

Ex. the following code appears to always fail to create a subdirectory.

```
File cacheDir = context.getCacheDir();
File subDir = new File(cacheDir, "subdir");
if ( !subDir.exists() ) {
    if ( !subDir.mkdirs() )
        Log.w(TAG, "Failed to create subdirectory in cache");
}
```

Comment: How have you determined that "Context.getCacheDir() seems to return a directory [you] cannot create subdirectories in"?

Comment: mkdir(s) returns false and any files I try to create in subdirectories aren't there (despite no IOExceptions getting thrown).

Comment: Post some code. AFAIK, there is no restriction on creating subdirectories in `getCacheDir()`.

Comment: Hey Bryant Harris, did you get any solution?

Comment: Chitrang as far as I can tell Android doesn't allow subdirectories in the caching directory.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried, I created subfolder successfully inside the `cache` folder.

I'm assuming maybe you've gotten a folder with the same name, maybe that's why you failed to mkdir?